# Ajax Customizable Error Callback Function

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, coffeescript

So this function works perfectly exceptI have six more buttons and do not want my code to have a ton of repeat code. For the customizing part I would like for each callback to be different for example the text append "Please Log In" to be different if the user is not admin and etc. How I can I make this customizable for each button? Thank You!

```
  error: (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) -> 
    console.dir arguments
    console.log("*| Status ", xhr.status)
    console.log("*| Error", thrownError)
    console.log("*| Ajax", ajaxOptions)
    if (not username? or not password?)
      $('#data-text').empty()   
      $('#data-text').append ("""<h1>Please Log In</h1>""")
      $('#input_username').fadeTo(100, 0.1).fadeTo(200, 1.0);
      $('#input_password').fadeTo(100, 0.1).fadeTo(200, 1.0);
      $('#header_user').css "background-color": "#d34242"
      $('#header_password').css "background-color": "#d34242"
      $('#data-text').css "background-color": "#d38642"
    else
      $('#data-text').empty()   
      $('#data-text').append ("""<h1>Failed Log In</h1>""")
      $('#input_username').fadeTo(100, 0.1).fadeTo(200, 1.0);
      $('#input_password').fadeTo(100, 0.1).fadeTo(200, 1.0);
      $('#header_user').css "background-color": "#d34242"
      $('#header_password').css "background-color": "#d34242"
      $('#data-text').css "background-color": "#d38642"
```

PLEASE Keep code in CoffeeScript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In CoffeeScript, you may define functions within functions. Don't let anyone tell you CoffeeScript or JavaScript is a functional language. Functions are first-class objects and objects can encapsulate other objects.

```
error: (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) -> 
  console.dir(arguments)
  console.log("*| Status ", xhr.status)
  console.log("*| Error", thrownError)
  console.log("*| Ajax", ajaxOptions)
  needsAGoodName = (msg) ->
    $('#data-text').empty()   
    $('#data-text').append(msg)
    $('#input_username').fadeTo(100, 0.1).fadeTo(200, 1.0)
    $('#input_password').fadeTo(100, 0.1).fadeTo(200, 1.0)
    $('#header_user').css("background-color": "#d34242")
    $('#header_password').css("background-color": "#d34242")
    $('#data-text').css("background-color": "#d38642")
  if not username? or not password?
    needsAGoodName("""<h1>Please Log In</h1>""")
  else
    needsAGoodName("""<h1>Failed Log In</h1>""")
```

I removed parenthesis around `if` and added them around function calls for styling. It works either way.